# I can't make the textview right of the cell inside grid view

Tags: android, gridview, textview, gravity

What i have is custom grid view and each row contains five columns and inside each cell i have a text view and i want this text view to be in the right side of the cell but it keeps showing on the left side .. as this image :
[image]

And here is my grid view xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myGridView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"        
        android:numColumns="5" 
        android:textDirection="rtl"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is textview style xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my main activity :

```
public class MyOrderNew extends Activity {

    private TextView text;
    private GridView gridView;
    private final String[] items = new String[]{"ملاحظات","مربع المساحة","الإرتفاع","العرض","الصنف","7","8","9","10","11"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart);



        gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
        gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        gridView.setVerticalSpacing(1);
        gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(1);
        CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MyOrderNew.this, items);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give width fill parent to the text view and give gravity right. or layout gravity right.

Answer (score 0):

Dont fix the Textview width make it fill_parent
android:layout_width="fill_parent"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```